# How to update the GOPATH for VS Code Go extension tools?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, gopath

My $GOPATH is `/home/shambhav/code_mis/golang`(current gopath), but long ago when I was setting up GO, I messed it up and GOPATH was `/home/shambhav/home/shambhav/code_mis/golang`(previous gopath). I noticed this and deleted the contents of `/home/shambhav/home/shambhav/code_mis/golang` and the directory itself and set GOPATH to the correct place.

Visual Studio Code seems to have stored `/home/shambhav/home/shambhav/code_mis/golang` as my GOPATH. And it isn't changing even after I changed my GOPATH. VSC obviously can't find my imports and things like gocode, goimports, golps etc in `/home/shambhav/home/shambhav/code_mis/golang`, VSC is kinda useless now. And also when I let VSC to download gocode, golps, etc to see what would happen, it remade /home/shambhav/home/shambhav/code_mis/golang` and put the files there.

I'm not going to switch my GOPATH because the directory is so weird, I will be made fun of if someone sees it, the only option is to update the GOPATH.

Some clarification, the Go compiler knows my actual GOPATH, it's just VSC not updating it.

So,

Long ago: GOPATH = `home/shambhav/home/shambhav/code_mis/golang`

VSC stored the Long ago GOPATH.

Now: GOPATH = `home/shambhav/code_mis/golang`

But VSC still thinks that the long ago GOPATH is still the real GOPAH and it is causing problems.

Comment: Do not use GOPATH builds. Its 2021 you must use modules only. So it doesn't matter what value you use for GOPATH; just have it unset (and let the tools use the default).

Comment: @Volker I am using modules. But VSC installs some stuff like gocode, goimports etc in GOPATH. So what am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the GOPATH for only the VS Code Go extension tools by specifying the `go.toolsGopath` property in `settings.json`

So, in `settings.json` that would be,

```
"go.toolsGopath": "home/shambhav/code_mis/golang"
```

After you made this change reinstall the tools and you should be good to go.

You can refer the following link for more details,
https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/settings.md